# Link placed in a PHP switch block is being called itself

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a strange problem. Today I started to get support requests from my users that their messages are disappearing without deleting them. I tested the messages script in different browsers, computers, telephones but didn't see this problem.

Then I updated Android system on my mobile phone and after that discovered that the problem really exists and happends the following:

User access file **messages.php** to read some conversation, for example:

```
https://mydomain/messages.php?do=conversation&userid=123
```

"conversation" block contains a link to delete the conversation:

```
<a href="/messages.php?do=deleteconvers&userid=<?php echo $userid;?>">Delete this conversation</a>
```

In some mysterious way when user access the block "conversation", at the same time automatically is being called the link to delete messages. When user access the same conversation again, there are no messages - all are deleted. This happends only in mobile phones, not in PC.

This is the structure of my script:

**messages.php**

```
switch($do) {

case "conversation":
<a href="/messages.php?do=deleteconvers&userid=<?php echo $userid;?>">Delete this conversation</a>
messages
messages
messages
messages
break;

case "deleteconvers":
//mysql query to delete messages
break;

default:
//conversations list
break;


}
```

Comment: You're already *in* php and you have `<?php echo $userid;?>` inside it. That should have thrown you an error. Plus injecting pure HTML into PHP. Either that's pseudo code or I am not grasping something.

Comment: I have more than 18000000 messages in the database. The script was working fine since june 2018. Since then i'ts untauched and noone reported such a problem. That's why I only posted a "pseudo" code. Is it possible that Android in some way calls all links included on the page?

Comment: Maybe there was a server upgrade and errors were suppressed.

Comment: perhaps this is a question you need to pose to the Android developers if there is so much at stake ( 180 million messages is a lot at stake )

Comment: if it were me, I'd put in logging on all of those cases and run it on android locally and see what gets hit. also I'd be logging what $do contains as well.

Comment: The problem is really mysterious. I have investigated every possible things but can not find any explication. Logfiles show that when user access a conversation, immediately there is a request to delete the conversation (link on the page is being accessed). This link is called not every time when user access the conversation but in some 80% of cases. Request for this link is coming without any referer. I tried to change the link, variable names etc but the same problem. Finally replaced the link with a button and the problem is gone. As I wrote, this problem exists only in Android.